# Make sync request with node js request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have an array of urls and want to request each of them with node js request module in a forEach loop becuase of large number of requests i want to execute each of theme one by one, but becauce of request module is async it execute all of theme, how can i force it to request one by one

Comment: By only executing the next one after the previous one has completed. you don't have to make the requests synchronous to accomplish that goal.

Comment: I think your way will work, i'll try that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `async` module to do a `eachSeries` iteration

**Installation**

```
npm install async --save
```

**Code example**

```
var async = require('async')
var urls = [ 'http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com' ]

async.eachSeries(urls, function (url, next) {
  request(url, function (e, r, b) {
    if (e) next(e) // handle error

    // i'm done, go to the next one!
    next() 
  })
}, onFinished)

function onFinished (err) {
  // I finished all the urls
}
```